# Form submit not working in loop using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, firebug, submit

In this website:http://www.lenovowarranty.co.in/contacttech.asp
I want to submit the first form(id-#splocator2) in a loop so as to get the address of service centers of all states.

I want each address to open in a new tab.
I'm using Firefox and I type the following code in the Firebug console.

But this code executes only once(and only single tab is opened with value=1, that is the first state only:

```
$("#splocator2").attr("target","_blank");
for(i=1;i<5;++i){
$("#stateid").attr("value",""+i);
$("#splocator2").submit();}
```

or even

```
$("#splocator2").attr("target","_blank");
$("#stateid").attr("value","1");
$("#splocator2").submit();
$("#stateid").attr("value","2");
$("#splocator2").submit();
```

How to make this form submit automatically for all "select" combo box values of states so that each address opens in a new window?

Answer (score 0):

Try using .each to loop over each of your form elements, and submit them that way manually.

```
$.each($('#splocator2', function(i, item) {
    $(item).attr("target","_blank");
    $(item).submit();
}
```

Comment: is this syntax correct? How would "i" increment automatically?

Comment: Yes, this is correct for jQuery. The i will keep the index of the current location and item has the reference to the actual item.

Answer (score 0):

Placing the _blank line within for loop is making it work:

$("#splocator2").attr("target","_blank");